# Vue Component not works even i register it follow the official manual

Tags: laravel, vue.js

just a very new to Vue 2.0, i actually use if for Laravel 5.4, now you can see from below link that i created one component which name is "canvas-chart", what actually i want show is a filterable table, and then to get more Json data from next steps, but now it always show me "Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option." , can not understand that i follow the official documentation to use it why it's not work?

```
    

    new Vue({
      el:'#filterTest',
      data:{
        keywords:[{"id":"9","name":"missy","phone":"21324234532"},   
      {"id":"3","name":"Mahama","phone":"345604542"},
      {"id":"2","name":"Bernard","phone":"241242542"}]
      },

  computed: {
  filterM: function () {
    var self = this
    return self.filter(function (word) {
      return user.name.indexOf(self.searchQuery) !== -1
     })
  }
}
    
    });

    Vue.component('canvas-chat',{
      template:'#canvasChart',
      props:['keywordsData']
    })
    <script type="text/x-template" id="canvasChart">
     <table>
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th v-for="key.id in keywordsData">
                 <span class="arrow" ></span>  
               </th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              <tr v-for="key.name in keywordsData">
               <td v-for="key.phone in keywordsData"> {{key.name}}</td>
             </tr> 
           </tbody>
         </table> 
    </script>

    <div id="filterTest">
     <canvas-chat keywordsData="keywords" ></canvas-chat>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. You must register the `canvas-chat` component first before you use it in the main component (put `Vue.component('canvas-chat', ...` before `new Vue(...)`).
2. Your `v-for` loops are wrong. They should be like `v-for="key in keywordsData"`, not `v-for="key.id in keywordsData"`.
3. The `v-for`s on the `tr` and `td` elements don't make sense; you will have to process the `keywordsData` first (perhaps in a computed property) to get it into the correct format you want, then loop over that.
4. You must bind the `keywordsData` prop in the template like this: `:keywords-data="keywords"`.